# React Hooks: using useState inside useEffect doesn't set the state immediately after first rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, gatsby

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-og782

The logic is simply: I used Gatsby.js with React to render a `Gallery` component

```
<StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      {
        allFile(
          filter: {
            extension: { regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/" }
            sourceInstanceName: { eq: "images" }
          }
        ) {
          edges {
            node {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 800, quality: 95) {
                  aspectRatio
                  src
                  srcSet
                  originalName
                  srcWebp
                  srcSetWebp
                  sizes
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <Layout>
        <Gallery minWidth={200} data={data.allFile.edges} />
      </Layout>
    )}
  />
```

This will give `Gallery` the image files for it to display.

Inside `Gallery`, I have these state

```
  const [allPics, setAllPics] = useState([]) <-- storing all the image files
  const [currentImgs, setCurrentImgs] = useState([]) <-- storing the images of the current tab
  const [tabs, setTabs] = useState([])
```

`useEffect`  to run only once when the component did mount

```
useEffect(() => {
    const allPics = data.map((img, i) => {
      img.node.childImageSharp.index = i
      return img.node.childImageSharp
    })
    setAllPics(allPics)
    setTabs(getAllTabs(allPics))
    // default tab when the page first loads
    setCurrentImgs(
      allPics.filter(({ fluid }) => fluid.originalName.includes(tabs[0]))
    )
  }, [data])
```

Then I render by this

```
<>
      <ProjectsContainer>
        {tabs.map(tab => (
          <Project
            key={tab}
            onClick={() => {
              setCurrentImgs(
                allPics.filter(({ fluid }) => fluid.originalName.includes(tab))
              )
            }}
          >
            {tab}
          </Project>
        ))}
      </ProjectsContainer>

      <Mansory gap={"0em"} minWidth={minWidth}>
        {currentImgs.map((img, i) => {
          return (
            <PicContainer
              index={img.index}
              selected={isSelected}
              key={img.index}
            >
              <Enlarger
                src={img.fluid.srcSet.split(" ")[0]}
                enlargedSrc={img.fluid.src}
                index={img.index}
                setIsSelected={setIsSelected}
                onLoad={() => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    refs[img.index].current.toggleOpacity(1)
                  }, 300)
                }}
                ref={refs[img.index]}
                realIndex={i}
              />
            </PicContainer>
          )
        })}
      </Mansory>
    </>
```

The problem is, the state `currentImgs` seems to remain an empty array, which is its default state after the `useEffect` runs, so when we first load the page, there is no current images to display. You have to manually click on any of these tabs to trigger `setCurrentImgs` again to display the current images.

So the problem seems obvious, which is, why is that in `useEffect`, only the state `currentImgs` is not set up correctly, when other state like `allPics` and `tabs` are set up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like class-based react components' lifecycle methods, specifically the async nature of `setState`, so too is the functional counterpart, the `useState` hook.  The current value of the hook remains static during the current render cycle until updates are "flushed" and the component is re-rendered. In your `useEffect` hook you are trying to access the `tabs` state value that hasn't been "synched" yet. You should instead access the tabs response array directly if you want the value in this render cycle.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const allPics = data.map((img, i) => {
    img.node.childImageSharp.index = i
    return img.node.childImageSharp
  })
  setAllPics(allPics)

  // get all tabs
  const tabsArray = getAllTabs(allPics);

  setTabs(tabsArray)

  // default tab when the page first loads
  setCurrentImgs(
    allPics.filter(({ fluid }) => fluid.originalName.includes(tabsArray[0]))
  )
}, []) // pass empty dependency array if you truly only want this to run on mount
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `useEffect` for this initial state loading. You can set the initial values of your state inside the `useState` hook, like so:

```
const [allPics, setAllPics] = useState(
  data.map((img, i) => {
    img.node.childImageSharp.index = i
    return img.node.childImageSharp
  })
)
const getAllTabs = imageObj => {
  return imageObj
    .map(({ fluid }) => fluid.originalName.split("-")[0])
    .filter((name, index, self) => index === self.indexOf(name))
}
const [tabs, setTabs] = useState(getAllTabs(allPics))
const [currentImgs, setCurrentImgs] = useState(
  allPics.filter(({ fluid }) => fluid.originalName.includes(tabs[0]))
)
```

You can see the working fork of your sandbox with these changes [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-tsf4c).

Comment: hi thank you for your answer. Actually I thought of this solution but by moving these set-initial-value functions outside of `useEffect`, doesn't we make them get called every time the component re-renders? Like if I put a `console.log("here")` inside those `useState` you put outside of  `useEffect`,  then when I navigate between tabs, we can see that `useState` is called more than once for the initial setup by knowing that "here"  is printed. I thought this might impact the performance.

Comment: `useState` initializers are only called once when the component mounts. If it is unmounted when switching tabs then it'll get called again when mounted.

Answer (score 0):

React useEffect use the session until each update/or we can say lifecycle until change.
just pass the parameters in useEffect from useState hook it will update the data,

don't try to pass the data variable it will run infinity loop. just pass the setData function.

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("effect");

        (async () => {
            try {
                let result = await fetch("/query/countries");
                const res = await result.json();

                let result1 = await fetch("/query/projects");
                const res1 = await result1.json();


                let result11 = await fetch("/query/regions");
                const res11 = await result11.json();
                setData({countries: res, projects: res1, regions: res11});

            } catch {

            }
        })()
    }, [setData])
```